# Port forwarding does not work

Tags: ssh, port, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am connecting to office network through VPN. I have two servers A and B. I have ssh/tomcat access to A through VPN but not to B. When I ssh into A, from there I can ssh into B. Also, B is running tomcat, which I can see though elinks on A.

I want to see the tomcat page of B on my remote machine browser. So I followed the instructions mentioned in [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/347499/how-to-assign-a-hostname-to-ssh-tunnel). I ssh-ed into A using ssh user@A -D 1234, changed firefox proxy settings to localhost:1234. But instead of the tomcat page on B, I keep getting "The connection was reset" error on firefox. Also, when I try going to google, I get the same error, surprisingly facebook works ([image: see attached image])

Chrome would only allow me to use system proxy settings, and when I changed that, I got the error "no data received" ("Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data"). Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: I think it's more of a security issue, as I don't get this error for https sites. Please do not migrate this to security.stackexchange, as I have a modified question there (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62914/port-forwarding-does-not-work-for-http-sites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Socks proxy only, leave the others blank (do not check the box for use the same..)

Comment: It wasn't checked anyway